# How do I create multiple objects with the same Obj C code, each with a unique name?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, object, namespaces

**How do I create multiple objects with the same code, but each with a unique name?**

If I create an object in objective C something like:

```
MyClass *myObject = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

I have an object named myObject that I can refer to, to do stuff like:

```
[myObject setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

But what if I want to create multiple objects with the same allocation code? For instance if I am using this code in an action so that every time a button is tapped a new object is created. Then I would have multiple objects named myObject. SO when I used the code to set the background color it would turn all of myObject's background color blue.

If each object created had a unique name this would not be an issue, but how to give each object created with the same code a unique name?

One way would be to rename the objects after creation and attach a number increment, but how can I rename an object?  Or maybe I could set each object created with a unique name in the first place, but how can I insert a unique "string" for the name of each new object?

Thanks for reading!

**UPDATE!!**

I created an "init with tag method", but each time I create a new object the previously created object also receives the new tag, so each object has the same tag, not unique tags. Any help?

The init method:

```
- (id) initWithTag:(int) theTag
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.tag = theTag;
    }
    return self;
}
```

The object creation code:

```
MyClass *myObject = [[MyClass alloc] initWithTag:tagCount];
tagCount ++;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same request, longer time ago.

I prefer to do it that way:

```
@implementation testViewController {
    NSMutableArray *myarray;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        myarray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) buttonClickMethod {
    MyClass *myObject = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    [myObject setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [myarray addObject:myObject];
    [myObject release];
}
```

So you have an array with separate objects in it. You can iterate through it. You even can set the initial backgroundColor - when you tap the button - to a color based on the users choice. (in my example the color always would be blue)

Comment: By the way: Arrays in Objective-C are very nice. They do not store the values directly, but only the pointers to it. Thus they are pretty memory efficient

Answer (score 1):

Create an initialization method that accepts a name:

```
MyClass *myObject = [[MyClass alloc] initWithName:@"Current Object Name"];
```

And `initWithName:` code:

```
- (id) initWithName:(NSString*) theName
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.name = theName;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer his question. He wants to create multiple instances of the same class, each instance has to have its own instancevariable. i.e. myobject1, myobjec2, myobject3...

Comment: maybe I can create a unique string for each object though and insert it where the string is. Thanks to both. I am trying to figure out exactly how to add the initWithName method to my subclass. So far it is not working, yet. Never added an init method before.

Comment: Just as any other method. Just remember to add it to the header file as well.

Comment: I always do `self = [self init];` in my `-initWithFoo:` methods.

Comment: Thanks All! I changed course just a bit to try to achieve what I want. I made an init with tag method. But at each initialization the tag for the previous object changes too, so I don't have unique tags.